# Object doesn't support property or method 'jtable'

Tags: javascript, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to test jTable in an MVC 4 default project (Visual studio 2013) by following this http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted tutorial. However, i keep getting the below error at the following line

> $('#PersonTable').jtable({

**The error is below**

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'jtable'

**And below is my .cshtml view file.**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "GatePassTypeList";
}

<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css") rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    ><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GatePassTypeList</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="PersonTable" style="width: 580px; margin: auto;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PersonTable').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '/GatePassType/GetGatePassTypeList',
                    createAction: '/GatePassType/CreateGatePassType',
                    updateAction: '/GatePassType/UpdateGatePassType',
                    deleteAction: '/GatePassType/DeleteGatePassType',
                },
                fields: {
                    PersonId: {
                        key: true,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Author Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    Age: {
                        title: 'Age',
                        width: '20%'
                    },
                    RecordDate: {
                        title: 'Record date',
                        width: '30%',
                        type: 'date',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the .js scripts are correctly loaded. (use the F12 browser inspector).
(is this line right? : `><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`)
and dont forget this:

```
$('#PersonTable').jtable('load');
```

To load the table.